# unable to remove special char % from url

Tags: php

I am trying to remove special character `%` from url.
I tried lot of solution like string_replace and etc. but not success.

I do not know what is wrong with my code:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (strpos($url,'pages') !== false) {
        $url = trim($url, '%');
    }
?>
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: try using `str_replace` like `str_replace("%", "",$url);`

Comment: can you share the $URL output

Comment: a percent character is %25 encoded. Have you tried running  `urldecode($string)` on your url string?

Comment: Just a note: When the URL is encoded certain characters are being encoded as well and being converted to strings like: %20%80... So when you're replacing the % characters you might affect the functionality of the request.

Comment: Tschallacka@  I am unable to get this

Comment: @sanjaykumar Like what Ivan said: can we please see the output of `$url`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**trim() -** Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string

This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the beginning and end of str. Without the second parameter, trim() will strip these characters:

- " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
- "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
- "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
- "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
- "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
- "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.

---

**FOR URL**

You can use urldecode to convert the URL string.

```
echo urldecode($your_url);
```

OR Use this function for Cleaning your URL :

```
function PerfectURL($your_url) {
  $perfect_url = strtolower(preg_replace( array('/[^a-z0-9\- ]/i', '/[ \-]+/'), array('', '-'), $your_url));
            return $perfect_url;
     }
```

OR Replace Only `%` by `''`

```
str_replace("%", "", $your_url);
```

Comment: S N Tiwari@Frient I used this but unable to solve this

Comment: S N Tiwari@Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Client sent malformed Host header

Comment: @sanjaykumar Which one you are using ?

Comment: @sanjaykumar What is your output for `echo $url;`

Answer (score 2):

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) should do the trick.
The following code will find all instances of "%" and replace it with a blank string which effectively removes it from the string.

[`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) will remove characters from the start and end of the string. Thus your example will only remove a `%` if it is at the beginning or end of the string.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($url,'pages') !== false) {
    $url = str_replace("%", "", $url);
}
?>
```

One thing to consider is that if you have a space in the URL then you'll end up with `20` remaining in the URL.

This is down to the way URLs are encoded and certain characters are encoded as such.
[See this link](https://secure.n-able.com/webhelp/NC_9-1-0_SO_en/Content/SA_docs/API_Level_Integration/API_Integration_URLEncoding.html) for more information. The column "Code Points (Hexadecimal)" is what you need to look at to see the encoded version. The space character is a common example and is encoded as `%20` thus, removing the `%` will leave you with `20` and that could cause problems with the URL further on.

---

Following the above note, if you want to remove a space and any numbers then you could use RegEx in the following way:

```
$url = preg_replace("/%\d+", "", $url);
```

Comment: JustCarty@its not working  any help, I told you i tried with string_replac

Comment: @sanjaykumar What does `$url` look like? can you do a `var_dump` for me immediately after declaring the variable? Currently the code will only run if the URL contains the word "pages"; if it does not then the `%` is not removed

Answer (score 1):

as per this documentation of [str_replace](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp) function, you can change your code with

```
<?php
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($url,'pages') !== false) {
    $url = str_replace("%", "", $url);
}
?>
```

Comment: @sanjaykumar, if you are working with urls then you can check this once: http://www.meridianoutpost.com/resources/etools/php-functions/php-urlencode-urldecode.php

Answer (score 0):

`urldecode()` is the best method to decode URL in PHP.

Ex:

```
urldecode("https%3A%2F%2Fwww.unitypoint.org%2Four-culture.aspx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy Tip:
Use Filename without space

like:
Filename with space
login foam.js or login foam.html
url= [www.abc.com/login%foam.html](http://www.abc.com/login%foam.html)

File Name without Space:

loginfoam.js or loginfoam.html
[www.abc.com/loginfoam.html](http://www.abc.com/loginfoam.html)

url= [www.hitechumair.rf.gd/index.html](http://www.hitechumair.rf.gd/index.html)

OR Use this Code:

str_replace("%", "", $your_url);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).